# Turn off VSCode "Convert to named function" hint

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code, editor

I personally prefer arrow funtion than JS named funtion. but that **light bulb** keep annoying me, it even hide my code sometimes ( yes, it in row 1 of editor ).

All I want is disable it. I tried some setting in `settings.json` but not found it.

[image: VSCode Hint]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's currently no way of disabling this specific feature as of `v1.71.2`

You can however turn suggestions from showing up by adding this to your `settings.json`:

```
"editor.lightbulb.enabled": false,
```

However - it's still accessable through `⌘ + .` on Mac OS X or `ctrl + .` on Windows. It just doesn't show up and block anything.

Comment: Thanks for answering, But it's still appearing. I added the setting to both vscode settings.json then reload window checked but still not work. then I added it to workspace settings.json => reload window but I still there

Comment: Hmm strange, I've updated the answer. Try this instead and let me know if it worked